# Access workdir defined on command line from within Snakefile

Tags: python, snakemake, workflow-management

Snakemake provides access to a `workflow` object within a Snakefile. This allows one to, for example, have dynamic programmatic access to the directory containing the Snakefile (via the `workflow.basedir` attribute). Is there a similar way to access the working directory that is specified on the command line using `--directory`?

Through a bit of exploration I was able to figure out that the `workflow` object has a `workdir()` method, but it appears this is used internally by Snakemake for registering working directories, not for access.

**UPDATE**: It looks like the working directory is stored internally as the `_workdir` attribute of the `workflow` object. However, this attribute is unset (default value `None`) when I'm creating static/global objects in the Snakefile. Is it impossible to access the working directory prior to building the workflow DAG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could query Python for the working directory within the Snakefile, since evidently Snakemake changes the actual working directory of the process to the one specified by `--directory`.    For example, using a stub Snakefile with just these two lines:

```
import os
print("Current working directory: " + os.getcwd())
```

And on the command line:

```
$ snakemake --directory working-directory
Creating specified working directory working-directory.
Current working directory: /home/jesse/dev/snakemake-wd/working-directory
Building DAG of jobs...
Nothing to be done.
Complete log: /home/jesse/dev/snakemake-wd/working-directory/.snakemake/log/2019-08-02T142009.349338.snakemake.log
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the type of thing that seems super obvious after you've pointed it out, but wasn't obvious initially.

Comment: No problem.  I wasn't sure myself if that was how they implemented `--directory` until I tried it out.  I guess it's an implementation detail but seems unlikely to me it'll change.